# How do I upload Amazon Seller reports into a SQL database?

Tags: sql, amazonsellercentral, azure-sql

I tried to load a csv file (>50 MB) into Azure SQL Studio, but the upload never finished despite two attempts.  Do you have any ideas on how to fix this?  Alternatively, to avoid the manual uploading, is there a way to directly pipe files from Amazon Seller reports into a SQL database, whether on Azure SQL Studio or elsewhere?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried breaking it into smaller chunks, e.g. 10x 5mb files? You shouldn't have to, but just a question. Which method of inserting into SQL are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would prefer not to break it up into smaller files.  I already have > 30 files, and I don't want to have to manually load 150 files instead.  I'm using Azure SQL Studio's import flat file wizard.